# redux-injectors: Using yield select in saga before reducer and saga are injected

Tags: redux, css-selectors, redux-saga, inject

Hello this is my first question. I am trying to set up a project where modules along with the redux and sagas will be injected into the main app, using redux-injectors. In my sagas I want to use yield select, to check if an action has updated the state and then carry on. For example, when I post an image, I want to make sure there were no errors in posting the file and then move on. I use the following function:
`export const imageErrors = (state: RootState): IImagesErrorState => state.image.errors`
and then in the saga.ts file I use it as such:

```
      if (imagesErrors?.postImageError !== null) {
        throw imagesErrors.postImageError
      }
```

this works fine as long as the state.image exists in the root state from the beginning. However, how do I do that when I want to inject this state later on using useInjectReducer and useInjectSaga? I obviously get an error
`Property 'image' does not exist on type 'Reducer<CombinedState<{ user: CombinedState<{ auth: IAuthState; errors: IErrorState; }>; }>, AnyAction>'.ts(2339)`
So how do we handle selectors of specific pieces of state, since state does not yet include them?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Can't talk about the Typescript part of things, but in terms of architecture you've got two options.

One is the obvious - that is to add conditions or `?` everywhere to avoid errors from accessing missing properties, but that can get tedious quickly.

The other probably better option is to rethink your state & application chunks. What is this saga that is accessing state that isn't existing yet? Does it need to run before you have such state? If not, let's move the saga to the same chunk as the  reducer. In the opposite case, where you need the saga to be running e.g. as part of the runtime chunk, then perhaps the image state should be in the runtime chunk as well.